# XSLT template match param containing xpaths

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to do an XSL Transformation of different XML responses, inserting processing instructions in to help identify list elements for later XMLtoJSON conversion.

Example input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe_collection>
   <last_updated>20170405</last_updated>
   <recipe>
      <name>Split Pea Soup</name>
      <ingredients_list>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Split Peas</name>
            <amount>1 bag</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Vegetable Broth</name>
            <amount>32 Ounces</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Vegetable Broth</name>
            <amount>32 Ounces</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Ham</name>
            <amount>Small</amount>
         </ingredient>
      </ingredients_list>
      <preparation>
         <step>Rinse Peas</step>
         <step>Add ingredients to pressure cooker</step>
         <step>Cook at full pressure for 12 minutes</step>
         <step>Season with salt, pepper, garlic powder to taste</step>
      </preparation>
      <serve_with>
         <name>Bread</name>
      </serve_with>
   </recipe>
</recipe_collection>
```

Example XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/recipe_collection/recipe/name[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/preparation/step[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/serve_with/name[1]">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
         <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which in turn copies the original XML with the `<?xml-muliple ...?>` PIs inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe_collection>
   <last_updated>20170405</last_updated>
   <recipe>
      <?xml-multiple name?>
      <name>Split Pea Soup</name>
      <ingredients_list>
         <?xml-multiple ingredient?>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Split Peas</name>
            <amount>1 bag</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Vegetable Broth</name>
            <amount>32 Ounces</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Vegetable Broth</name>
            <amount>32 Ounces</amount>
         </ingredient>
         <ingredient>
            <name>Ham</name>
            <amount>Small</amount>
         </ingredient>
      </ingredients_list>
      <preparation>
         <?xml-multiple step?>
         <step>Rinse Peas</step>
         <step>Add ingredients to pressure cooker</step>
         <step>Cook at full pressure for 12 minutes</step>
         <step>Season with salt, pepper, garlic powder to taste</step>
      </preparation>
      <serve_with>
         <?xml-multiple name?>
         <name>Bread</name>
      </serve_with>
   </recipe>
</recipe_collection>
```

So far so good. Now to make this XSL work with different XML schemas. I would like to pass in a parameter containing the paths used in the match.

In the modified stylesheet, I'm defining the parameter "xpaths" with the list of default paths (note, the value for this param will actually be passed to the XSL during runtime):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:param name="xpaths">/recipe_collection/recipe/name[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/preparation/step[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/serve_with/name[1]</xsl:param>

   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="$xpaths">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
         <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However the `match="$xpaths"` in the new XSL is invalid

Other things to note:

The XSL parser I'm using allows XSL 2.0.

The XSL must work for any schema including ones where elements may not have unique names, so the full xpath must be used to specify the lists.

And finally my apologies for being an XSL newb. I still have trouble getting my brain around some of the transformation concepts.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction (or solutions).

Answer (score 0):

With an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.7 EE or PE you should be able to use a static variable and a shadow attribute e.g.

```
  <xsl:param name="xpaths" static="yes" as="xs:string">/recipe_collection/recipe/name[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/ingredients_list/ingredient[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/preparation/step[1]|/recipe_collection/recipe/serve_with/name[1]</xsl:param>

   <xsl:template _match="{$xpaths}">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">
         <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
      </xsl:processing-instruction>
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

With pure XSLT 2.0 you need to use one stylesheet taking your string path(s) as the argument to then output/generate the desired second stylesheet with the inserted match attribute value.

Comment: Thanks. That works well in the XML 3.0 evaluator. Unfortunately the tool I'm using, Axway, is constrained not only to XSLT 2.0 or lower and it doesn't allow you to reference a generated stylesheet.

I suspect there is probably a complex way to do it in 2.0. My other option is to not use Axway's XSLT processor and hook in the Saxon one you mentioned.